# Cannot disable menu from popping up when right click scroll area

Tags: python, pyqt

I have tried PreventContextMenu as well as NoContextMenu, but the menu still pops up when I right click the scroll area. Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image: Right-click popup menu]

The menu items are basically "Scroll to here","Left edge", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set it on the scrollbar, not the scrollarea:

```py
scroll_area.horizontalScrollBar().setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
```